# USB-Insert Authentication for Linux

Tags: usb, privileges, removable-storage

On Windows, when I insert a USB, I use USB Security. So I'd get "To allow USB access, enter a password." So I'd have to enter a password to be able to even view USB contents or run it. Is there such software or configuration for Linux?

Here's an image

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific for those of us who don't know what USB Security is... Is it about password protecting (encrypting/locking) a USB drive or about preventing users to access USB drives ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [udisks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/), which, you can restrict what permissions a user has in regards to removable devices with [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/)

There are some good example configurations shown [here](https://gist.github.com/grawity/3886114)