# Configure udisks permission

Tags: permissions, udisks

On my Debian Stretch, my USB drive is auto-mounted on login, AFAICT. It is placed under `/media/currentuser/DRIVENAME`. I suppose `udisks` takes care of this (but I could be wrong). No entry in `fstab` relate to that disk.

I would like other users to have (read and write) access to the drive, and (relatedly) I would like to change its default mount point (which does not make sense if the drive is to be shared accross several users).

I suppose it is possible to do it by adding an entry for that drive in `fstab`, as often advised. But I would like to know if it is possible to rather configure `udisks`? I have read that `polkit` can be used for this, and I suspect it will offer more options and be “more modern” than the `fstab` way. But I have been unable to find information about how to do this. (For example [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177277/96622) answer points to examples which suggest to add polkit rules in the `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/` folder, but this does not exist on my system, which lets me suppose that this advice is somewhat outdated or not applicable to me.)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can use an `udev` rule to configure a disk as shared, which should result in `udisks2` mounting it to `/media` instead of `/media/user`:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Mount_to_/media_(udisks2)

`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisks2.rules`:

```
# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
```

Comment: This, sadly, applies to all filesystems. I would like to expose one directory on the mounted filesytem to other users (or even better, a few specific users).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `polkit` is what you're looking for. It allows you to control [permissions related to programs and actions on your system](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) but it does not allow you to change the functioning of those programs/actions. If you decide to use `polkit` for a purpose other than what you're asking about here, the configuration files in Debian/Ubuntu are located at [`/usr/share/polkit-1`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/udisks2/filelist).

You are correct that [`udisks`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/udisks2/udisks.8.en.html) is taking care of your auto-mounting. Despite what the user in your link states, there is no way to configure `udisks` as stated in their answer. The example they give shows command line mounting, not a configuration.

The best way of achieving your goal is indeed to use [`/etc/fstab`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mount/fstab.5.en.html). A line such as

> /dev/XXX /media/DRIVENAME auto user,umask=0000 0 0

will achieve what you're trying to accomplish.